# How to fix "Dimension too large" error when outputting large pdf file?

Tags: pdftex, standalone

I have to create a pdf file with a lot of information.

This code:

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 850px 0pt 850px}]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,pagecolor,lipsum,pbox,graphicx,anyfontsize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\graphicspath{./images/}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{1600px}

\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

{\fontsize{16}{26}\selectfont

Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]

}%End fontsize

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

When I try to export the pdf file and have a lot of content, I get the following error:

```
! Dimension too large.
\height ->\ht \@tempboxa 

l.35 \end{minipage}
```

So I tried to separate the content into several minipages (they are not perfectly below each other but for testing it's ok):

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 850px 0pt 850px}]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,pagecolor,lipsum,pbox,graphicx,anyfontsize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\graphicspath{./images/}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{1600px}

\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

{\fontsize{16}{26}\selectfont

Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]

}%End fontsize

\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{1600px}

\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

{\fontsize{16}{26}\selectfont

Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]
Test\\[50cm]

}%End fontsize

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

but then I get a more global error:

```
! Dimension too large.
\sa@placebox ...lobal \pdfpageheight =\ht \sa@box 
                                                  \fi \global \paperwidth =\...
l.51 \end{document}

?
```

Is there any way to fix this without re-setting the sizes of the minipage, fonts, margins, etc.?

Maybe some way to set the dimensions of the resulting pdf file?

Comment: You have a 6-meters-long document. Do you really need to have such a giant size?

Comment: It's a very special use case. As it is a vector graphic I could simply reduce all the font sizes etc. but just telling the pdf converter to make a smaller pdf would be ok, too and far less complicated.

Comment: I get the error `! Improper \prevdepth` from your first example

Comment: I will add the missing `\end` to the question...